# Q&A site for personal grooming

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Q&A site for personal grooming on the SE Network? Something which deals with grooming your hair, skin, wearing clothes and other things dealing with personal grooming.

Comment: Care to comment what's wrong in the question?

Comment: It may be people thinking that such a site would not be useful on the Stack Exchange network.  I see that one has now been proposed http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88174/personal-grooming.

Comment: @PolyGeo: That was OP.

Comment: While I don't agree such site should exist, this question here is totally legit so +1 for asking and following the given advice.

Comment: @Dronehinge makes a good point here about the female/male ratio. Moreover, initially why I wanted such a site was for male grooming, like for males who wish to keep long hair. But expanding it for female things makeup and such will bolster its proposal and make it more useful.

Comment: 7 downvotes? That slightly degrades one's faith in online communities... There is nothing wrong with the question, nor is it a feature request so downvoting does not state "I don't want this" it states "you shouldn't ask this". Pah, meh, pfft, etc

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no such site.

You can always propose one on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) (or support one if it already exists).

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll do that. May I ask why people have down-voted my question? What's wrong in the question?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. In order to recommend a site you need to give us the specific question you want to ask.

Comment: @shivams there may be another reason to down-vote your question "They did not agree with your proposal"